# PKCE for confidential clients in Spring 5 (non-reactive)

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, oauth-2.0, pkce

I'm trying to enable PKCE on an oAuth client in Spring Boot 5. The examples I can find are for reactive client, looking something like this:

```java
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver pkceResolver = new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository);
        pkceResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());

http.oauth2Login(login -> login
    .authorizationRequestResolver(pkceResolver)
```

I tried converting this to the servlet equivalent, but the oAuthLoginConfigurer for that doesn't have an `authorizationRequestResolver` method to set the PKCE resolver.

This is where I got to:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http
          ,ClientRegistrationRepository repo
  ) 
  throws Exception {

    var resolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo,"https://myoauthserver.com");
    resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());
    
    http
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(); // doesn't have the authorizationRequestResolver method like reactive



    return http.build();
  }
```

Any ideas how to make this work for servlet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out and thought I'd better not leave this question hanging for poor souls in the future (ie. me when I forget how it works).

Here is the magic bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, ClientRegistrationRepository repo)
      throws Exception {

    var base_uri = OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI;
    var resolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo, base_uri);

    resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());

    http
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(login -> login.authorizationEndpoint().authorizationRequestResolver(resolver));

    http.logout(logout -> logout
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: The PKCE thing for Spring Security is criminally underducumented

Comment: `authorizationEndpoint()` is now deprecated. Would you know how to update this to work with the new way?

Comment: It appears if you have the correct parameters and the client is properly set, it picks up that it should use PKCE.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the deprecation issue related to `authorizationEndpoint()` you can use

```
.authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpointConfig -> authorizationEndpointConfig.authorizationRequestResolver(resolver))
```